# ZK Tomcat - NotSerializableException: ResetableInputStream

Tags: session, tomcat, deserialization, zk

we are using ZK 7.0.3 for this project and (sometimes, not always) get this error when restarting tomcat, which leads to the session being lost, which is quite annoying.

It seems to be that something (zk?) puts a ResetableInputStream into the session attributes, but I have no idea when and where? Does anyone have a good idea how this could happen and how to prevent it?

> 10:43:26.777 [localhost-startStop-1]
>   ERROR
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad
>   (305) - IOException while loading
>   persisted sessions:
>   java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing
>   aborted;
>   java.io.**NotSerializableException**:
>   org.zkoss.io.**RepeatableInputStream$ResetableInputStream**
>   java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing
>   aborted;
>   java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.zkoss.io.RepeatableInputStream$ResetableInputStream
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_45]

Comment: Look Like in your project few classes not implement the serializable interface.Mainly these issue come to cluster enviorment

Comment: 7.0.47 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug and has fixed here - [ZK-2936 issue](http://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-2936)